# Using loops to set a tab title in Android

Tags: android

I have encountered a problem in my Android application where I cannot set tab titles in a loop.  Here is my source code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText("Converter")
                        .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
```

If I try to insert a comma, then put the title of another tab, like this:

```
                                .setText("Converter", "Currencies", "News")
```

Eclipse is giving me an error.  I have scoured all over the internet to find the answer, but nothing works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set text to tabs? Do you mean set the tab title, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I mean the tab title.

Comment: Be specific on your question its quite misunderstood by people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **String Array** you can do this,

Like,

```
String[] tabTitle = {"Converter", "Currencies", "News"};
```

And then,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(tabTitle[i])
                        .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
```